# how to convert int to char, char to int after get an input

Tags: c++

I just jumped in studying cpp and don't know much so far.

I learnt 'if' grammar recently and just made a homework for myself.
You get an input from user. It can either be a character or number.
When he typed a number, it shows what he typed and it needs to be changed to a character according to ASCII table.
And vice-versa.

I've searched about this for awhile but seems like people are using loops but I haven't learnt it yet. So I'm not going to use it in this homework.

Here comes my code that I've tried, but don't know what's wrong.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a Number between 65 to 122 or an Alphabet character : ";
    char in_char;

    cin >> in_char;

    if ((in_char) >= 65 && (in_char) <= 122) // checking for alphabet
        cout << in_char << " " << static_cast<int>(in_char) << endl;

    else // if input is not an alphabet, it's a number and it should be turnd to a character
        cout << in_char << " " << static_cast<char>(in_char) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output do you expect if input is not alphabet?

Comment: why do people write `65` instead of `'A'`

Comment: When a user input 65, it will come out 65 A. If 'A', it comes out A 65.

Comment: `static_cast<char>(in_char)`. `in_char` is already a `char`, doesn't need a `static_cast` again

Comment: So if the user types `9`, what should the output be?

Comment: com'on we both know the alphabet is between 65 and 122. 9 in ASCII seems 'Horizontal Tab', but I don't know what it is. The user should type the number between 65 to 122. I'll change the question.

Comment: How do you expect to read **2-characters** (e.g. `"65"`, being `'6'` and `'5'`) into one `char`?

Comment: Not allowed to use for loop? How about stringstream? Or char array?

Comment: Or read the value as a `string` and then use `.stoi()`? Or read it as an `int` with similar validation and then static cast to `char`?

Comment: I hope you know `std::string` already and allowed to use it, otherwise we can't process more than 1 character

Comment: No, we both don't know that. *I* don't know that. Why would I need to? The code of the letter A is spelled `'A'` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I understand what you are wanting to do without a loop. Though you may need to remove the limit I have placed on integer input to insure a single-digit is input to translate to ASCII `'0'->'9'`. If I follow your question, you want to be able to take either a number or a character, validate it is in the range of `[A-Za-z]` or `[0-9]`, and output the corresponding ASCII character and ASCII character value (or vice versa).

For Example if the user enters the following, you want similar output to:

```
    input   output
    -----   -------------------------------------------
       5    '5' 5
     121    'y' 121
       y    'y' 121
     200    error: integer out of range
       =    error: character no within requested range
       P    'P' 80
```

In order to accomplish this task, you essentially need to attempt a read of an integer, validate whether an unrecoverabel `cin.eof() || cin.bad()` occurs and exit with error. Otherwise `cin.fail()` occurs and the input was non-integer and remains in `stdin` where you can `cin.clear()` the *failbit* and then attempt a character read.

With the character read, you have the same basic validations, except there is no reason to clear the *failbit* as your attempt to read an integer and then character has failed at that point.

On a good read of either `int` or `char`, you simply need to perform the wanted validation to insure the `int` or `char` was within range and then format your output as desired.

A short example with necessary validations could be as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    cout << "Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : ";
    int in_int;
    char in_char;

    if (!(cin >> in_int) ) {    /* attempt read of int */
        /* if eof() or bad() return error */
        if (cin.eof() || cin.bad()) {
            cerr << "(user canceled or unreconverable error)\n";
            return 1;
        }
        cin.clear();            /* clear failbit */
    }
    else {  /* good integer read */
        if (in_int >= 0 && in_int <= 9) {        // checking ASCII [0-9]
            cout << "'" << (char)(in_int + '0') << "' " << in_int << endl;
        }
        else if (in_int >= 'A' && in_int <= 'z') // checking ASCII [A-Za-z]
            cout << "'" << (char)in_int << "' " << in_int << endl;
        else {
            cerr << "error: integer input out of range.\n";
            return 1;   /* return failure */
        }
        return 0;       /* return success */
    }

    if (!(cin >> in_char) ) {    /* attempt read of char */
        /* if eof() or bad() return error */
        if (cin.eof() || cin.bad()) {
            cerr << "(user canceled or unreconverable error)\n";
            return 1;
        }
        else if (cin.fail())    /* if failbit */
            cerr << "error: invalid input.\n";

        return 1;
    }
    else {  /* good character input */
        if (in_char >= 'A' && in_char <= 'z') // checking ASCII [A-Za-z]
            cout << "'" << in_char << "' " 
                    << static_cast<int>(in_char) << endl;
        else
            cerr << "error: character not within requested range.\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/cinonechar
Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : 5
'5' 5

$ ./bin/cinonechar
Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : 121
'y' 121

$ ./bin/cinonechar
Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : y
'y' 121

$ ./bin/cinonechar
Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : 200
error: integer input out of range.

$ ./bin/cinonechar
Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : =
error: character not within requested range.

$ ./bin/cinonechar
Enter a digit or upper or lower case character : P
'P' 80
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions. You can adjust the test of `int` value range to correct any misunderstanding I have on the range you intend with your question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your beautiful code. You got exactly what I wanted. But because of my short knowledge, I can not understand fully about your code. I've got to dig into it from now!